# HTML5 pattern doesn't accept after one invalid entry

Tags: angularjs, html

I am using html5 pattern in an angularJS app, after the page load it works fine if i enter valid inputs, and if i once enter an invalid input it notifies the error, but after that it won't accept any value. It shows error on both valid and invalid inputs.

Following is the code i am using.

```
<div class="col-md-6 userform-leftspace">
    <div class="form-group  madotory-border">
        <input type="text" id="regular1" class="form-control" ng-model="systolicBp" pattern="/[0-9]{1,2,3}/" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid reading')" required>
        <label for="regular1">Systolic Bp</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please have a look and help me solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: `[0-9]{1,2,3}` is an incorrect regex. If you mean "from 1 to 3 numbers", use `[0-9]{1,3}` or `\d{1,3}`

Comment: I want any number having maximum three digits.

Comment: `\d{1,3}` should do the trick then. I'm not sure it will fix your problem, but your current pattern is incorrect : the regex quantifier `{}` has only four syntaxes, `{n}`, `{n,}`, `{,m}` and `{n,m}`

Comment: It works the first time, and gives error if i enter invalid input. But right after i input a wrong value, it stops accepting the valid values as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in your input tag:

```
oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"
```